# Post method returning 405 Method not allowed in Angular 8 web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular8

I have a problem with the post method in my register.service.ts as it should return 200 OK, but instead, it returns 405 method not allowed. I am struggling with this error for some time and I know it because I have to allow it in the header configuration and CORS middleware. I have created a middleware class which I pass it in startup.cs along with other CORS configuration as follows:

```
  public class Startup
    { 
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            Configuration = configuration;

        }
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
 {
  options.UseApiBehavior = false;
  options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
 });
     services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5001").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/";
            });


});
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserService<>), typeof(UserService<>));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }


            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }
 app.UseOptions();//this is the method from the CORS middleware class
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the register.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment'; import { Register } from '../Models/register';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterService {

baseurl = 'https://localhost:5001';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
Create(user): Observable<Register> {
  const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type':
  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'})};
  return this.http.post<Register>(this.baseurl + '/register', JSON.stringify(user),
  httpOptions).pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

GetById(id: number) {
  let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
  return this.http.post(this.baseurl + '/register/' + id , {headers: reqHeader});
}
GetAll() {
  let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/register/', {headers: reqHeader});
}
Update(user: Register) {
  let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
  return this.http.post(this.baseurl + '/register/editUser', user, {headers: reqHeader});
}
Delete(id: number) {
  let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl  + '/register/deleteUser/' + id, {headers: reqHeader});
}
errorHandler(error) {
  let errorMessage = '';
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // Get client-side error
    errorMessage = error.error.message;
  } else {
    // Get server-side error
    errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
  }
  console.log(errorMessage);
  return throwError(errorMessage);
}
}
```

I have also replaced the x-www-form-urlencoded with application/json but it has the same behaviour both in the browser and Postman.

This is the RegisterController.cs class:

```
  [EnableCors]
[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RegisterController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
         private readonly IUserService<Register> _repo;
        public RegisterController(DataContext context,IUserService<Register> repo)
        {
            _context = context;
            _repo=repo;
        }

        // GET: api/Register
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Register>>> Getregistrations()
        {
            return await _context.register.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Register/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Register>> GetRegister([FromRoute]int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = await _context.register.FindAsync(id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(user);
        }

        // PUT: api/Register/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutRegister([FromRoute]int id,[FromBody] Register register)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != register.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(register).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            _repo.Update(register);
            var save = await _repo.SaveAsync(register);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!RegisterExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Register
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.


        [Route("PostRegister")]
        [HttpPost]
        [HttpOptions]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Register>> PostRegister([FromBody] Register register)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _repo.Add(register);
        var save = await _repo.SaveAsync(register);
             return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetRegister), new { id = register.Id }, register);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Register/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Register>> DeleteRegister([FromRoute]int id)
        {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = await _context.register.FindAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _repo.Delete(user);
        var save = await _repo.SaveAsync(user);

        return Ok(user);
        }

        private bool RegisterExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.register.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }


    }
```

I have no idea why it's not working. Can someone please help me figure it out? Please let me know if you need more details.

UPDATE:

I have tried what sam suggested and I get the same result as before:
This is in Postman:
[Postman result for POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwNGH.png)
And this is from the browser:
[Browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS5gB.png)

UPDATE 2: After trying with [FromForm] instead of [FromBody] with application/json as header:
for https://localhost:5001/register get same error 405 
for https://localhost:5001/register/PostRegister getting 500 
[for register/PostRegister](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BZyj.png)

I forgot to specify that my route path is configured to https://localhost:5001/Add
STACKTRACE:

```html
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (53ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `register` (`Email`, `Name`, `Password`)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
      SELECT `Id`
      FROM `register`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `Id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'AnotherAP.Helpers.DataContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null
       ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 774
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 49
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
         at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 774
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 49
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 774
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 49
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at AnotherAP.Helpers.UserService`1.SaveAsync(T entity) in /Users/Chsyn/Projects/copyofAAP/AnotherAP/Helpers/UserService.cs:line 35
   at AnotherAP.Controllers.RegisterController.PostRegister(Register register) in /Users/Chsyn/Projects/copyofAAP/AnotherAP/Controllers/RegisterController.cs:line 110
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
```

This is how my Create() method looks now in register.service.ts:

```html
baseurl = 'https://localhost:5001';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
Create(user): Observable<Register> {
  const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    })
};
  return this.http.post<Register>(this.baseurl + '/register/Add' , JSON.stringify(user),
  httpOptions).pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

Comment: I don’t see a single method that has POST allowed and is for `/register` so that causes the error. You have a POST method for route `PostRegister` though... Also you’re using *server side* headers on the *client side*, that doesn’t work.

Comment: whats your api url and whats your localhost? Only POST method have issues ?

Comment: Thank you for your response!I don't understand how can I make it so that it would work.I have the path:https://localhost:5001/register/ and I have also tried with [Route("register")] in the controller and in register.service.ts I declared the base url as:https://localhost:5001/register and for post:  return this.http.post<Register>(this.baseurl + '/', JSON.stringify(user),
  httpOptions).pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.errorHandler));

Comment: Eldho for now I'm only interested for the POST method to work,but I have tested GET method and GET based on id and they both work returning a json response both in browser and Postman

Comment: sam I tried every method possible for CORS configuration.I have also tried as you suggest by having only Content type in angular header config and the CORS middleware created on the server side but it didn't work.

Comment: @Ed12M 405 means, request is not in expected format by server (which MVC action in this case). So only I said CORS is not an issue here.

Comment: Which endpoint is used for the form-request? If you want to use form-data, your model must be binded with `[FromForm]`.

Comment: @alsami I have changed the [FromBody] to [FromForm] and I am tried to post to both: https:localhost:5001/register and https:localhost:5001/register/PostRegister but for the second I am getting 500 Internal Server error

Comment: If you get a 500 that means there is an error on your side. If you are using form-data you are supposed to use `[FromForm]`. I'd suggest to use the debugger and see where the 500 error is happening. When you are posting from the front-end (Angular) using `FormData` and set the keys, you don't have to add the headers manually.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try modifying httpOptions as below, please post your observations after trying this:

```
const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
                             { 'Content-Type': 'application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
                             { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 
                               /*'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
                               'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'*/
                             })
                    };
  return this.http.post<Register>(this.baseurl, JSON.stringify(user),
  httpOptions).pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

Comment: sam I have made the changes suggested and I have the same behaviour.You can find the screenshots in the update section of my question.

Comment: Per your screenshot (Browser Result), I see that MVC action url is incorrect. Its trying to post to register/postRegister/register. Could you remove /regsister from `this.baseurl + '/register'`. Also, please add application/json to content-type. Please post your observations.

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace of 500?

Comment: ok so there is a little bit tricky.The endpoint I am using for the post method is https://localhost:5001/register/Add since I have the route path to the form as https://localhost:5001/Add and i changed in RegisterController.cs [Route("PostRegister")] to [Route["Add"]] so it's localhost/controller/action and the stack trace is in the update section.It seems like now it tries to insert the data but the property email is null for some reason...

Comment: stack trace shows that email is can not be null (meaning not supplied). `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Column 'email' cannot be null`

Comment: I am writing the info for every field including email so i don't understand why is this property that has problems and nothing else.The logic is the same for all properties in my model.

Comment: Since input request is not pasted here, its hard to make assumptions here. I would have a break point in controller action and debug further.

Comment: thanks for all your help.It brought me close to understanding why is not working properly.I will try to debug and see what stops the method from saving the data.